# Google Sheets - Color duplicates uniquely

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using the custom formula:

```
 =countif(3:3,C3)>1
```

To text-color duplicate cells, but both a/a and b/b are coloured the same. Is it possible to have each unique set of duplicates be a different color?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't do this, the only option is to use script. I suggest using [Gradient Conditional Formatting](http://www.appscare.com/2015/04/add-gradient-conditional-formatting-rules-google-sheets/) in another column.

---

### Step1.

Paste column next to your column with data, column B in this sample. Suppose, the data column is A, then paste this formula in cell B2:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(--(countif(A:A,A2:A)>1)*MATCH(A2:A,A:A),0))
```

It will expend automatically.

[image]

---

### Step 2

Make custom number format in column B to make numbers invisible. Set your number format to:

```
;;;
```

---

### Step 3

Make Conditional Formatting for column B, select *gradient* and choose appropriate colours:

[image]

The result is neat column with conditionally coloured duplicates, each in it's own colour. You may additionally filter column B to select each group of duplicates (but need to make them visible).

Comment: Great answer. Any idea how to do this with a "random" color for each though? So that they don't look so similar?